# The following SQL query takes about 3 hours to run, I am I doing something wrong, can this be tuned?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

Please help to tune the following sql query, it takes about 3 hours to execute, I am doing it correctly ?

```sql
SELECT COUNT(P.POSTID)
    FROM QUAD.PostVersion P
    INNER JOIN QUAD.PostMapping PM
    ON PM.PostID       = P.PostID
    AND PM.LASTVERSION = P.VERSION
    INNER JOIN QUAD.USER_ U
    ON P.MODIFIEDUSERID = U.USERID
    WHERE content IS NOT NULL
    AND DBMS_LOB.INSTR(UPPER(content),'LINK') > 0
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is lacking of indexes within tables. Also this expression `DBMS_LOB.INSTR(UPPER(content),'LINK') > 0` will not use an index.

Comment: In reference to JW's comment, can you include your database structure? I'm thinking `INSTR` is slowing you down. Possible to configure your table to use a different method of indicating "LINK"?

Comment: How big are the tables? Can you also attach the schemas including indexes? Perhaps you need a full-text index or something.

Comment: Provide an execution plan.

Comment: The use of `INSTR` the way you are means that it's going to be called on every single row where `CONTENT IS NOT NULL`, and then you compound that by calling `UPPER` on every one of those rows as well. This would be even worse if the `CONTENT` column is a very large amount of text. If those are necessary, you need to modify your schema to remove that need by providing a new column for a keyword `CONTENT_KEY` or something similar that is already forced to UPPERCASE, so you can remove both of those function calls and properly utilize indexes, or even an extra table of key values you can `JOIN`.

Comment: Unfortunately the database cannot be modified since it is a database provided by a vendor. The size of the db is huge ( 40+ million records) I tried removing the UPPER from the method but it was not much helpful. I could find an alternate method to DBMS_LOB.INSTR. Please suggest if there is an alternate way to this method.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues to look at - a regular expression will be faster for large amounts of text than INSTR+UPPER and make sure the condition is not evaluated more than once for each record in the table it's coming from. For the first use REGEXP_LIKE(), for the second would need to know what table `content` is coming from.

```
SELECT COUNT(P.POSTID)
    FROM QUAD.PostVersion P
    INNER JOIN QUAD.PostMapping PM
    ON PM.PostID       = P.PostID
    AND PM.LASTVERSION = P.VERSION
    INNER JOIN QUAD.USER_ U
    ON P.MODIFIEDUSERID = U.USERID
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(content,'LINK','i')
```

Note: REGEXP_LIKE supports CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, NVARCHAR2, CLOB, or NCLOB columns.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for your response. "content" is coming from table QUAD.PostVersion

Comment: Hi Brain, I am re-running the query with your recommendations, can you please help me understand the second part of your reply "make sure the condition is not evaluated more than once for each record in the table it's coming from." How do I make sure it is evaluated only once ?

Comment: You can look at the query plan.